# I Have a JSON response in string so I used JSR223 processor and extracted the required token

Tags: api, jmeter-5.0

I Have a JSON response in string so I used JSR223 processor and extracted the required token, is there any way to make that variable as global variable for all the threads to use

COuldn't get any slutions or haven't got the right link to check

As per request I have added screenshot for more clarity in my question
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBzgU.png)

I even tried   using

$(_setProperty(text3,${token},)};

still no use

I have extracted a string from response and assigned to text3  and I want to make it as global variable in thread group so that It can be used all other next API's I tried using props.put() however it didn't worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated the question  and comments I have extracted a string from response and assigned to text3 and I want to make it as global variable in thread group so that It can be used all other next API's I tried using props.put() however it didn't worked